# In CVS how to ignore a file which is already checked in

Tags: version-control, cvs, ignore

In our CVS (not git!) repo I have a file which I checked in a while ago. Now we have decided not to keep it in version control.

How can I keep the file in my local directory but tell CVS not to store it? Just adding it to .cvsignore (obviously) doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Copy it to a different name, check in its removal, maybe sync with the server, move it back. It's been too long since I used CVS to remember whether "sync with the server" is necessary, or even makes sense for CVS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) mentioned in the comments, the following works:

1. Move the file in question out of the repository (but don't delete it).
2. Check in the removal of the file.
3. Commit the change to CVS.
4. Move the file back into its location the repo.
5. Add it to the appropriate `.cvsignore` file.

Done.